# Using React where JSON input has unique keys?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to using React, and I'm trying to make a table that lists a word with the number of occurrences. The incoming input is JSON in a form like so:

```
{"hello":5,"world":6,"foo":1,"bar":20}
```

The keys are not known beforehand, so how do I pull the key/value pair?

Answer (score 3):

```
<table>
  <thead><tr><th>word</th><th></th>occurrences</tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    { Object.keys(data).map(key => (
      <tr key={key}><td>{ key }</td><td>{ data[key] }</td></tr>
    )) }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys